# How to attach logo to pdf file and send to mail

Tags: php, pdf, html2pdf

My question is about to how to show the logo at the generated pdf file and send it to mail? I am using html2pdf class to generate my pdf and I am getting pdf file to my mail but when I am using img tag it gets an error. **How to use image tag?**

```
<?php
$content .= '<td>Jersey Size :  ' . $result->r_jerseysize . '</td> </tr>';
$content .= '<tr>
              <td style="padding:0 80px 0 -15px;"><img src="https://www.example.com/certificates/cert.jpg"></td>
            </tr>';
$content .= '<tr>
               <td style="padding:10px 0 14px 0;">Full Name: ' .$name. '</td>
            </tr>';
?>
```

Comment: Your image in on an extern website or on your server ?

Comment: Have you tried using a relative path, not absolute URL to the image? I had troubles like this sometimes.

Comment: @Fizik26 image is on my server. When I am using image tag without passing image URL to src it gets an error and I am not getting pdf in mail

Comment: and if you put only `/certificates/cert.jpg` in your src ? if certificates is a folder if the folder is where index.php is.

Comment: Thank you @Fizik26 I used the only certificates/cert.jpg in my src and finally I got the image at PDF.

Comment: I will ad an answer and you can accept it :) Cool if it's working now :)

Comment: Don't forget to  vote up the validate answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you host the image on your server you can use something like that :

```
<?php
$content .= '<td>Jersey Size :  ' . $result->r_jerseysize . '</td> </tr>';
$content .= '<tr>
              <td style="padding:0 80px 0 -15px;"><img src="certificates/cert.jpg"></td>
            </tr>';
$content .= '<tr>
               <td style="padding:10px 0 14px 0;">Full Name: ' .$name. '</td>
            </tr>';
?>
```

With the path from your index.php => 'certificates/cert.jpg'

Answer (score 0):

You can use image logo in

```
<tr>
<td>  </td>
<td>  </td>

</tr>
```

you can also use row or container of bootstrap